# reloadData с другого viewController

Tags: база-данных, swift, model, uiviewcontroller

В контроллере А у меня находится окно поиска и кнопка
по нажатию которой происходит запрос в базу, добавление информации в модель и ее декодинг.

После отправки и получения запроса мне нужно удаленно перезагрузить collectionView в контроллере Б и сразу вывести в нем ячейки с заполненой информацией.

Я прошерстил много тем, но все они безнадежно устарели.

Прошу помощи по нескольким вопросам:

1. после внесение в модель данных, могу ли я их сразу использовать на всех других контроллерах, просто обращаясь к данным через полный путь? например: `model.gov!.body`
2. если да, как удаленно с первого VC передать команду на `reloadData` во втором?

Я пробовал уже много вариантов. Включая строку

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {self.collectionView.reloadData()}
```

В `viewDidLoad`

при переходе на второе представление - ячейки остаются с дефолтной информацией.

Вот к слову строки благодаря которым происходит переход между view

```
button.stopAnimation(animationStyle: .expand, completion: {
                    let secondVC  = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CarInfoID") as! CarInfo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2. если да, как удаленно с первого VC передать команду на reloadData во
>      втором? Зачем вам удаленнно передавать команду и обновлять данные? - обновляйте их при отрисовке данного экрана (во viewWillAppear).

Comment: Правильно ли я изначально понял?

Если данные были загруженные на главном VC и были переданы в модель - они остаются в ней. 

и я могу их спокойно вызывать и использовать на любом из дальнейших видов

Comment: Если модель это глобальные объект то да. Если нет то при переходе они пропадут, чтобы они не пропали используйте сингелтон (одиночка) в модели и эти данные будут доступны отовсюду. final class Singleton {

    // Can't init is singleton
    private init() { }

    //MARK: Shared Instance

    static let sharedInstance: Singleton = Singleton()

    //MARK: Local Variable

    var emptyStringArray : [String] = []

}